# Razor pages, detect text changes in textview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page where the user can make some options from a dropdownlist and than enter some value.
See attached image

[image]

What i want to achieve is that as user change any of the textboxes, call the appropriate handler function.
So as soon user enter some value in the textfield 1, the one to the right of textlabel "Some value" i want to do some calculation and update the textfield 2, the one to the right of textlabel "Some other value" . And vice versa for the other textfield.
I have following code

```html
@page
@model CurrencyConverter.Pages.ConvertModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Convert";
}



<div>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ResultInfo))
    {
        <p>@Model.ResultInfo</p>
    }



</div>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurencyModel.FirstCurrency, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Value", "Text"), "Select currency", new { @class = "css-class" })

        <input asp-for="CurencyModel.TotalAmountFirstCurrency" />
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurencyModel.SecondCurrency, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Value", "Text"), "Select currency", new { @class = "css-class" })
        <input asp-for="CurencyModel.TotalAmounSecondCurrency" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="FirstCurrency">Submit first currency</button>
        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="SecondCurrency">Submit second currency</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

the cshtml.cs file looks like this

public class ConvertModel : PageModel
{

```
[TempData]
public string ResultInfo { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public CurrencyModel CurencyModel { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options
{
    get; set;
}


public ConvertModel()
{
    //initalization
}
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostFirstCurrency()
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    //given first currency calculate the second from the first using some formula
    
         
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSecondCurency()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    //given second currency calculate the second from the first using some formula
}
```

}

what i want to achieve is in

```
<div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurencyModel.SecondCurrency, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Value", "Text"), "Select currency", new { @class = "css-class" })
<input asp-for="CurencyModel.TotalAmounSecondCurrency" onchanged=asp-page-handler="FirstCurrency"/>
```

But this seems not possible with only pure razor and c# syntax.

Comment: You use JavaScript to detect changes in the UI. Look at the jQuery change event: https://api.jquery.com/change/. Then look at this example that shows how to call page handler methods in the change event handler: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/cascading-dropdowns

Comment: For m it's still not clear how to solve it. Can you give some short example code. The reason is that I am not good at all at javaScript or jquery.

Comment: First of all, provide a comprehensive view of the code you are currently involved in(with .cshtml.cs code).Second, when do you want to start calculating the formula? And do you want to trigger in handler or just in jQuery? What's their calculation formula?

Comment: I have updated the question with more code, see above